# Place div buttons static

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these thumbnails with a div which contains those two buttons, but I haven't figured out how to align them statically like the third thumbnail, no matter if the text above adds a row.

[image]

this is my div:

```
<div class="static" role="group" style="margin-top: 1cm">content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the containing div's position relative and use absolute positioning to keep everything tidy.

This article has a good walkthrough and explanation:
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/